# How to connect Sick s300 Expert to PC for ROS

Tags: slam, navigation, communication, ros-kinetic, laserscanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- **OS:** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with 4.15.0-52-generic kernel
- **ROS version:** Kinetic
- **ROS Package:** cob_sick_s300
- **Device:** Sick s300 Expert Safety Laser Scanner (S30B-3011GB)
  [image: image description]
- **Cable:** DSL-8U04G02M025KM1 (RS232 to USB)[image: image description]
- **Pinout of Device:** [image: image description]
  [Click Here To See Pins](https://i.ibb.co/jMytKJQ/20190820-165830.jpg)

Hello. Now, I need to receive scan data from Sick s300 Expert for Navigation&SLAM. But I don't know how I'll connect it to the PC. I've tried with the configuration cable but It didn't work with cob_sick_s300. It supports RS422 interface, should I try with a **RS422 to USB** converter? It also has a EFI(Enhanced Function Interface). Datasheets says that I can use it as an Ethernet interface but I don't know how I can do it.

I checked [This Link](https://answers.ros.org/question/63215/attaching-an-sick-s300-advanced-to-a-pc-with-ros/).
@bernhard says on the comments: "It is able to do the same as the **codai_sick_s300** just for the programming interface per rs232" But codai_sick_s300 is not available right now and what is the thing that we can read the data through the  **RS232 to USB** cable

Note:  I was using Hokuyo UAM-05LP with using Ethernet. It worked with **urg_node**, for Hokuyo the USB interface was not working for data acqusition, the USB interface was just for configuration with it's own program. Only the Ethernet interface was working with ROS. I guess I can not use urg_node for Sick scanners because of the **SCIP** protocol.

**Edit:** I corrected a mistake: changed cob_sick_s300 to codai_sick_s300

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331161/how-to-connect-sick-s300-expert-to-pc-for-ros/) by [ermanas](https://answers.ros.org/users/43196/ermanas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2019-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-08-20**:
You're better off contacting SICK directly, this is more general connection issue than a ROS issue.

**Comment by [ermanas](https://answers.ros.org/users/43196/ermanas/) on 2019-08-21**:
Thanks and I see, sure I'll do it as well but I also wanted to ask people how do they connect their sick scanners.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ermanas

You need a Serial-to-USB Converter that works well with Ubuntu and supports **RS422**. There are quite a few available. I personally have good experience with the VSCom USB-2COM-PRO.

Then, you need to connect the RS422 serial pins of the scanner (i.e. Pins 11, 12, 23, 24) to the respective pins of the converter. (Note: this is serial, so Rx=Receive goes to Tx=Transmit!)

Lastly, the driver: I have no clue what you mean with

> cob_sick_s300 is not available right now

It is released into [kinetic](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=cob_sick_s300) and [melodic](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=cob_sick_s300), [source](https://github.com/ipa320/cob_driver/blob/kinetic_dev/cob_sick_s300) is available, and [the Readme](https://github.com/ipa320/cob_driver/blob/kinetic_dev/cob_sick_s300/README.md) has some hints about configuration.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ermanas](https://answers.ros.org/users/43196/ermanas/) on 2019-08-21**:
Thank you for your answer. I'll try it with the converter.
So sorry @mgruhler , my mistake. I wanted to write codai_sick_s300.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-08-21**:
no worries. I was just confused :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Contributors: @PeteBlackerThe3rd , @mgruhler

I wrote an email to Sick and I asked for the connections with ROS.
They said s300 doesn't have ROS support from Sick. But if you want to use the raw data with ROS:

- You **CAN** only use the RS422 output with a proper converter ([Isolated Converter](http://www.vscom.de/usb-com-plus-iso.html) - [CircuitBoard Converter](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ftdi-future-technology-devices-international-ltd/USB-COM422-PLUS1/768-1035-ND/2139297))
- You **CAN'T** use the configuration port with using the [RS232 to USB cable](https://www.sick.com/ag/en/dsl-8u04g02m025km1/p/p314713). This is just for configuration.
- You **CAN'T** use the [EFI](https://www.sick.com/media/pdf/4/64/864/IM0032864.PDF) interface to acquire raw data. This is only for Flexi Soft Controllers.

Sick has an official ROS package named [sick_safetyscanners](http://wiki.ros.org/sick_safetyscanners) for [microscan3](https://www.sick.com/ag/en/opto-electronic-protective-devices/safety-laser-scanners/microscan3-core/c/g295658) series safety laser scanners.

After I tried the s300 with the converter, I'll update the answer.

Thank you,

Ermanas.

---

Originally posted by [ermanas](https://answers.ros.org/users/43196/ermanas/) with karma: 46 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-08-27**:
completely correct. Probably should have stated that more clearly.

Note that the data output via RS422 is NOT "safe". This is what the EFI is for. But for the typical use case of navigation this is not an issue.

**Comment by [cowboygary](https://answers.ros.org/users/45703/cowboygary/) on 2019-09-16**:
Hi @ermanas , i have the same problem as you. may I know you try with which package?

**Comment by [ermanas](https://answers.ros.org/users/43196/ermanas/) on 2019-09-18**:
I will use the [cob_sick_s300](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_sick_s300) If I can get the converter. Now I'm working with Hokuyo UAM-05LP with using [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node) and Pepperl Fuchs r2000-HD with using [pepperl_fuchs_r2000](http://wiki.ros.org/pepperl_fuchs_r2000)